# Create new column status base on criterial in the same column with Condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

i have the following data

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE (CustomerID INT, CustomerName VARCHAR(100),Product VARCHAR(100), Status_Col VARCHAR(100))
-- INSERT DATA
INSERT INTO @TBL VALUES     (90,'Wilman Kala','Dairy','Simple'),
    (90,'Wilman Kala','Grain','Other'), (90,'Wilman Kala','Dairy','Other'), (81,'Hipermercados','Produce','Simple'),
    (81,'Hipermercados','Produce','Other'), (34,'Hanari Carnes','Seafood','Simple'),(34,'Hanari Carnes','Produce','Simple'),
    (34,'Hanari Carnes','Condiments','Simple'), (85,'Smith stock','Grains','Other'),    (86,'Jane will','Cereals','Other'),
    (87,'Victuailles en stock','Condiments','Simple'),  (88,'Suprêmes délices','Confections','Other'),
    (88,'Suprêmes délices','Dairy','Other'),    (89,'Marry Dawson','Dairy','Simple'),(90,'Eve Lawson','Dairy','Other'),
    (91,'Hanari Carnes','Beverages','Other'),   (91,'Hanari Carnes','Confections','Other'),
    (92,'Mark Johnson','Beverages','Other');
```

I want to create a new column that will show customer who have ‘simple’  then ‘simple’ from `Status_Col`,if they have  ‘other’ then ‘other’. If however they have ‘simple’  or other’  at any stage the Status_Col column then I want the `NewStatus` to show it  `Other/Simple` .`In my data CustomerID 81 and 90 should show`Other/Simple

I have tried the query bellow it is not giving me the correct answer

```
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName,Product,
Status_Col,
CASE WHEN Status_Col='Other' THEN 'Other'
     WHEN Status_Col='Simple' THEN 'Simple'
     WHEN Status_Col='Other' OR Status_Col='Simple' THEN 'Other/Simple' END AS NewStatus
FROM @TBL
order by CustomerName
```

Current output

```
CustomerID  CustomerName            Product         Status_Col  NewStatus
90           Eve Lawson             Dairy              Other      Other
91           Hanari Carnes          Beverages          Other      Other
91           Hanari Carnes          Confections        Other      Other
34           Hanari Carnes          Seafood            Simple     Simple
34           Hanari Carnes          Produce            Simple     Simple
34           Hanari Carnes          Condiments         Simple     Simple
81           Hipermercados          Produce            Simple     Simple
81           Hipermercados          Produce            Other      Other
86           Jane will              Cereals            Other      Other
92           Mark Johnson           Beverages          Other      Other
89           Marry Dawson           Dairy              Simple     Simple
85           Smith stock            Grains             Other      Other
88           Suprêmes délices       Confections        Other      Other
88           Suprêmes délices       Dairy              Other      Other
87           Victuailles en stock   Condiments         Simple     Simple
90           Wilman Kala            Dairy              Simple     Simple
90           Wilman Kala            Grain              Other      Other
90           Wilman Kala            Dairy              Other      Other
```

Expected ouput

```
CustomerID  CustomerName            Product         Status_Col  NewStatus
90           Eve Lawson             Dairy              Other      Other
91           Hanari Carnes          Beverages          Other      Other
91           Hanari Carnes          Confections        Other      Other
34           Hanari Carnes          Seafood            Simple     Simple
34           Hanari Carnes          Produce            Simple     Simple
34           Hanari Carnes          Condiments         Simple     Simple
81           Hipermercados          Produce            Simple   Other/Simple
81           Hipermercados          Produce            Other    Other/Simple
86           Jane will              Cereals            Other      Other
92           Mark Johnson           Beverages          Other      Other
89           Marry Dawson           Dairy              Simple     Simple
85           Smith stock            Grains             Other      Other
88           Suprêmes délices       Confections        Other      Other
88           Suprêmes délices       Dairy              Other      Other
87           Victuailles en stock   Condiments         Simple     Simple
90           Wilman Kala            Dairy              Simple   Other/Simple
90           Wilman Kala            Grain              Other    Other/Simple
90           Wilman Kala            Dairy              Other    Other/Simple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT CustomerID,CustomerName,Product,
Status_Col,
CASE WHEN (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Status_Col) 
            FROM @TBL AS T1 
            WHERE T0.CustomerID = T1.CustomerID 
            AND T0.CustomerName = T1.CustomerName
           ) > 1 THEN 'Other/Simple'
     WHEN Status_Col='Other' THEN 'Other'
     WHEN Status_Col='Simple' THEN 'Simple' END AS NewStatus
FROM @TBL AS T0
order by CustomerName
```

I have to wonder, though, why do you have multiple customer names for the same customerId.

Answer (score 1):

Your `CASE` expression makes little sense (the final expression would never be true as one of the prior expressions would have had to be true already). It seems you're trying to inspect the values of other rows, while not refering to the dataset as a whole.

This appears to be the answer you want:

```
SELECT CustomerID,
       CustomerName,
       Product,
       Status_Col,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE Status_Col WHEN 'Simple' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, CustomerName) > 0
             AND COUNT(CASE Status_Col WHEN 'Other' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, CustomerName) > 0 THEN 'Other/Simple'
            ELSE Status_Col --If both values don't appear, then it must be the current one
        END AS NewStatus
FROM @TBL
order by CustomerName;
```